# What would the blood work look like for someone on a very high protein diet?

Tags: diet, side-effects, blood-tests

What will blood test results look like for someone on a very high protein diet consuming 1-2g of protein per pound of bodyweight? Is it healthy to maintain such a diet?

Comment: The process relevant to your question is called protein catabolism. It's relatively complex, but you might want to start by looking into that term. If it helps, proteins are composed of chains of amino acids, and typically get broken down into polypeptides (very short amino acid chains), amino acids, and proteoses and peptones, basically combinations of the two. These are further broken down into ammonia, methane, and a number of sulfer-containing compounds, among others. I hope that gives you a nice list of terms and processes to get your search started. It's a good question.

Comment: I'm looking for creatinine values or levels of uric acid, just to name a few examples.